# Close all pop-up windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I know there are many questions of this ilk with many answers.

I know that I can use

```
var popup = window.open('');
```

and can later use

```
popup.close();
```

to close that window.

However, is there a way to close all children without having to store the window.open result?

That is, could I do

```
window.open('1');
window.open('2');
window.open('3');
```

and then somehow do a global "Close" call that will close these three windows?

If not, could I accomplish it by using the following code to do the open?

```
window.open('1','window1');
window.open('2','window2');
window.open('3','window3');
```

Comment: You could store the window objects returned by `open()` in a global array, or maybe in an object, indexed by window name. Then you would only have to iterate over this array / object.

Answer (score 7):

You can make a new function that basically wraps the existing functionality with what you're trying to do.

```
var WindowDialog = new function() {
    this.openedWindows = {};

    this.open = function(instanceName) {
        var handle = window.open(Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 1));

        this.openedWindows[instanceName] = handle;

        return handle;
    };

    this.close = function(instanceName) {
        if(this.openedWindows[instanceName])
            this.openedWindows[instanceName].close();
    };

    this.closeAll = function() {
        for(var dialog in this.openedWindows)
            this.openedWindows[dialog].close();
    };
};
```

**Sample Usage**

```
WindowDialog.open('windowName', /* arguments you would call in window.open() */);
WindowDialog.open('anotherName', /* ... */);
WindowDialog.open('uniqueWindow', /* ... */);
WindowDialog.open('testingAgain', /* ... */);
WindowDialog.open('finalWindow', /* ... */);

// closes the instance you created with the name 'testingAgain'
WindowDialog.close('testingAgain');

// close all dialogs
WindowDialog.closeAll();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote and I like your approach better than the other answer but there are a couple things wrong with it.  First, `arguments` isn't a real array so you can't call `splice` on it.  Instead you want to do something like `Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments,1)`.  Also, the `new function()` pattern seems a little odd.  You could make it an object literal instead `{ openWindows : {}, open : function(instanceName)...}`.

Comment: You're right about `arguments` - good to know. As for the `new function()` pattern, I can't access `this` keyword in an object literal.

Comment: You should be able to. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TBVcJ/)

Answer (score 2):

try this to open and close

```
document.MyActiveWindows= new Array;

function openWindow(sUrl,sName,sProps){
document.MyActiveWindows.push(window.open(sUrl,sName,sProps))
}

function closeAllWindows(){
for(var i = 0;i < document.MyActiveWindows.length; i++)
document.MyActiveWindows[i].close()
}
```

Comment: Using global variables isn't a good idea.  Using a name (activeWindows) that sounds like something that might actually be used by a browser in the future is even worse.

Comment: @go-oleg, sometimes there is global state to be maintained, and even though I agree expanding `document` is not a good idea, expanding `$` or another global object should not be frowned upon, when you have to. Closures for the sake of closures are not always the right way to go.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Good point.  The important thing is to namespace them properly to avoid conflicts.